# exclude dependancy while using rosdoc

Tags: ros, rosdoc, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I have a ros stack, which I like to generate its documentation using rosdoc. but then it generates documentation for alot of other ros packages.
I'd like to generate documentation only for my packages
I'm aware of the exclude attribute for the rosdoc configuration, but it excludes a pattern, and I want to exclude dependancy
Any ideas?
thnx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12173/exclude-dependancy-while-using-rosdoc/) by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just run "rosdoc " it should just document that package, though older versions of rosdoc had a bug that would cause the behavior you described.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-12-04**:
works perfectly, also under diamondback. Many many thanks

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-02**:
If you pass in multiple packages, it should create a common index.html.  I believe diamondback may still have the  bug.

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-12-02**:
I have diamondback
I don't want to run rosdoc on single packages, there are alot of packages, and also because it will create separate doc folders, with no common index.html